# Одноразовый ключ усложняющий доступ к сессии

Tags: php, сессия, php7

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать одноразовый токен, который усложнит доступ к сессии?

Например, генерируем ключ, записываем его в базу вместе с датой и id пользователя, когда ключ вернулся удаляем, если время действия ключа истекло, тоже удаляем. Я не пойму, как вернется ключ? То есть это случится при краже кук? Не особо понял способ реализации. Может еще есть какие-либо способы реализации.

Comment: ничего не понял... куки и так врЕменные. сессии вполне неплохо закодированны. Шо надо?

Comment: @DNS Я спокойно беру значение куки и подставляю в другой браузер и авторизация успешно проходит. Хочется предотвратить это. Вот шо надо!

Comment: Так же спокойно можно будет взять и одноразовый ключ, как вы куку берете :)

Comment: @Visman Этот совет я вычитал в одном из вопросе о сессиях, поэтому не могу разобраться с ним. Если у вас есть, что посоветовать, буду только рад.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема надуманная(почти).

Если человек может скопировать ручками куки то защищаться бесполезно! Доступ и к приложению и к машине жертвы уже есть.

От чего надо защищать:

1. Что бы вам на страницу нельзя было вставить js, который передаст данную куку без ведома пользователя.
2. В формы добавить csrf токен. Который генерируется сервером при создании формы(так же можно включить csrf защиту на уровне сервера). https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFProtector_Project
3. Для особо критических действий(снятие денег,  смена емайла в профиле...), можно попросить пользователя ввести пароль еще раз.